# Django - filter related objects within model. 'ReverseManyRelatedObjectsDescriptor' object has no attribute 'filter'

Tags: django

This is my model:

```
class Delivery(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_(u"Name"), max_length=50)
    permissions = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True)
```

I'm creating a method to return True or False t check if a certain user can view a certain row:

```
@classmethod
def can_view(self, user):        
    permission = self.permissions.filter(permissions = user);        
    return permission is not None;
```

And when trying to use this method I get this error: `'ReverseManyRelatedObjectsDescriptor' object has no attribute 'filter'`

As you can see I don't know how I can check if the user has permission: `permission = self.permissions.filter(permissions = user);`. How can I get the related within the model?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can't have a class method and expect `self` to work; `self` is for instance methods.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared this to be a classmethod, instead of a normal instance method. So the first parameter, which you've named `self`, is actually the class, not an instance of it; and the class itself doesn't have any related objects.

There's no reason for this to be a classmethod; remove that decorator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately it didn't work, the permissions are still empty

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should fix your `can_view` method so it is not a class method, remove `@classmethod`

The line `self.permissions.filter(permissions = user)` probably won't work if you're trying to filter on the User. The `filter()` method is expecting a list of keyword arguments, with the models field name as the key and the value you're filtering on as the, well, value.  Here you are filtering on your User model, so you probably want to filter on a field like `id` (or `pk`), `email`, `username`, or some other unique field. Give the 
[docs for `.filter(**kwargs)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#filter) a read.

For your query, I'd recommend using `return self.permissions.filter(pk=user.pk).exists()`.  I'm filtering on `pk` because this is simple and guaranteed to work.

i.e.

```
def can_view(self, user):
    return self.permissions.filter(pk=user.pk).exists()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues here:

1. As others mentioned, `self` and `@classmethod` don't go together. `self` refers to the instance, so its for instance methods.
2. Your ORM query is also not correct as `permissions` is a ManyToMany field, and you need to access it accordingly.

Try this method:

```
def can_view(self, user):
   return self.permissions.filter(pk=user.pk).exists()
```

However, you really don't need this method as all `User` objects will have a `delivery_set` model (see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)), so you can simply do:

```
def check_if_delivery_belongs_to_user(request, delivery_pk=None):
    delivery = get_object_or_404(Delivery, pk=delivery_pk)
    if request.user.delivery_set.filter(pk=delivery.pk).exists():
        print('You can access this')
    else:
        print('Nope, you cannot')
```